# OnPause not executing code in cordova/phonegap :(((

Tags: android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

Its a week yet and I still get problems integrating the cordova into ana ndroid webview!
Before the onPause and onResume were working fine but after integration they dont trigger anymore.
Even though I see this in my console:

```
07-15 17:01:21.880: D/CordovaActivity(5635): Paused the application!
07-15 17:01:21.880: D/CORDOVA_ACTIVITY(5635): onPause
```

but the code inside the opPause function isn't executing!! I'm really tired of this.. I tried a week non stop to get it working.

This is my main java file:

```
package com.Snap.What;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class WhatSnap extends CordovaActivity implements CordovaInterface
{
    private CordovaWebView cordova_webview;
    private String TAG = "CORDOVA_ACTIVITY";
    private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cordova_layout);
        cordova_webview = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.cordova_web_view);
        // Config.init(this); 
        cordova_webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        cordova_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        cordova_webview.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");


    }





    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        private Activity activity;

        public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
            this.activity = activiy;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showLog(){
            Log.v("blah", "blah blah");
        }


    }


    @Override 
    protected void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    } 


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy(); 
        if (this.cordova_webview != null) {
            this.cordova_webview
                    .loadUrl("javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};"); 
            this.cordova_webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
            cordova_webview.handleDestroy();
        } 
    } 



    @Override 
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
    } 


    @Override 
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
        return threadPool;
    } 


    @Override 
    public Object onMessage(String message, Object obj) {
        Log.d(TAG, message);
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            super.finish(); 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
//
//
//    @Override 
//    public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin cordovaPlugin) {
//        Log.d(TAG, "setActivityResultCallback is unimplemented");
//    } 


//    @Override 
//    public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin cordovaPlugin,
//            Intent intent, int resultCode) {
//        Log.d(TAG, "startActivityForResult is unimplemented");
//    } 


}
```

I tried also to comment the onPause and onresume from java but than I only get this in console:

```
07-15 17:01:21.880: D/CordovaActivity(5635): Paused the application!
```

In my js I have these lines:

```
 document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", punish, false);
```

and the coresponding functions wich WONT EXECUTE!

I really don't know why they're not executing.. Please take a look and you you have any idea pls tell me.

Comment: Please make sure you are adding listener after deviceReady event of cordova. You can add it on deviceReady event handler.

Comment: @Rupesh I added it in the deviceready function..

Comment: Strange!!.. I am using same and its working fine. I believe device ready handler is getting executed in ur case, right?

Comment: @Rupesh yes man.. only the onPause and onReady events dont work, other work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Its an old post, still if some one is following

Change

```
document.addEventListener("pause", punish, false);
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
```